# What is correct way to upgrade Debian 8 to 9 on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a virtual server running Debian 8, and I want to upgrade it to Debian 9. The server has MySQL, PHP, and Apache server installed on the same disk. What is the correct way to accomplish this? Do I need to change the source list and upgrade, or is there something else I should do?

Comment: The correct and recommended way on Google Cloud Platform is to create a new VM instance, configure the new instance and copy your files from the old instance. In-place upgrades are not recommended. If the inplace upgrade requires information or a confirmation step on reboot, you will not be able to provide that information remotely.

Comment: @JohnHanley If you believe this is the correct answer, would it be possible if you can post it as such in order to help out the community?

Answer (score 4):

The correct and recommended way on Google Cloud Platform is to create a new VM instance, configure the new instance and copy your files from the old instance.

In-place upgrades are not recommended. If the inplace upgrade requires information or a confirmation step on reboot, you will not be able to provide that information remotely.

Additionally, software libraries are often OS version specific. Updates needs to be applied or rebuilt. OS configuration files change. OS inplace upgrades cannot take into consideration the effects that the upgrade will have on installed applications.